# Were early military planes not pressurized?

Tags: military, aviation-history

I just heard that  1930s-40s planes such as the [B-17](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_B-17_Flying_Fortress) were not pressurized. Is this true? If yes, then how did the military men survive at heights of 30k ft?

Comment: The slightly more recent (but still WWII) B-29 did have a pressurized cabin.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There were a few problems:

- Pressurization (while not impossible) was difficult requiring extra effort. It also increased weight and complexity.
- Pressurization was still a relatively new technology at the time. For reference, the first pressurized commercial aircraft, the [Boeing 307 Stratoliner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_307_Stratoliner), made its first flight later the same year (1938) as the B17. Note that it was developed from the B17.
- There was an incredible amount of openings on early planes for gun turrets, bomb bays, etc. Sealing these off airtight would have been a impractical nightmare. You would traverse the bomb bay move to the back and front of the plane.
- It's also better from a reliability standpoint- it's pretty easy to damage and make a hole in the fuselage, but everybody having their own oxygen masks removes that single point of failure.
- While perhaps (I imagine) not incredibly comfortable for long duration missions oxygen masks worked fine.

30,000ft corresponds to around 9,200m, although that altitude is a ceiling defined by Boeing. With full load, they never achieved those altitude and hung around a lot lower. While I can't verify it, these [forum posters](http://www.armyairforces.com/Typical-altitude-for-B17-missions-m72178.aspx) appears to suggest that 19,000ft-28000ft with bombs was more common.

To do the math, the partial pressure of oxygen at sea level is around 0.21 bar. If you're being fed 100% oxygen through your mask, this is the same pressure as at 11,000m.

[image]
*Photo by Margaret Bourke-White, Sept. 1942, from the LIFE Archives.*